# How to make whole screen scrollable in Viewpager Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, gridview, scrollview

I have grid view and Listview(including pagination) in scrollview.

This is resulting individual scroll but i need whole screen scrollable with pagination. i tried to use NestedListView & ExpandableHeightListView but not working properly.

Any suggestion would be grateful.

```
enter codXML::
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingBottom="75dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/all_tpcs_heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/bg_horizantal_magzine_listview"
            android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:text="all topics"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <com.healthyliving.live.utils.ExpandableHeightGridView
            android:id="@+id/topicsGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/all_tpcs_heading"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/six_dp"
            android:clipChildren="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/six_dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="none"
            android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/six_dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rcnt_artcls_heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topicsGrid"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/six_dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
            android:text="Recent articles"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/recent_articles_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rcnt_artcls_heading"
            android:dividerHeight="@dimen/list_view_divider" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/load_progreebar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Fragment::

```
recentArticleAdapter = new ExploreRecentArtilcesAdapter(getActivity(),      featuredArticles);
    mRecentArticles.setAdapter(recentArticleAdapter);
```

Comment: ListView and Gridview optimisation doesn't work if it is nested within a Scroll. All the views inside it is drawn at once. So probably you should consider using a single Gridview with one / more columns based on your requirement.

Comment: Is pagination working correctly? If I am not wrong you require expandable height list-view and grid-view both inside scroll-view. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use below given custom list and grid view instead of default `ListView` and `GridView` in your layout xml file.

Custom ListView :-

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

Custom GridView :-

```
public class CustomGridView extends GridView {

    public CustomGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

In this approach, if you find any difficulties in vertical scroll and horizontal swipe(As you have view pager) use below custom `ScrollView` class instead of default scroll view in your layout xml file.

```
public class VerticalScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private float xDistance, yDistance, lastX, lastY;
    public VerticalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                xDistance = yDistance = 0f;
                lastX = ev.getX();
                lastY = ev.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final float curX = ev.getX();
                final float curY = ev.getY();
                xDistance += Math.abs(curX - lastX);
                yDistance += Math.abs(curY - lastY);
                lastX = curX;
                lastY = curY;
                if(xDistance > yDistance)
                    return false;
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Use all these custom view classes in a same way you used `com.healthyliving.live.utils.ExpandableHeightGridView` custom view in your current implementation. Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: I tried to use all of these custom classes.. its scrolling full but in hanging not smooth manner